# jquery fancybox scroll only fancybox, background static

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm using fancybox which works great, but, if I have a page which i load using ajax selector, I want the broswer scrollbar to only scroll the fancybox page, and leave the background static, is this possible?

Real world example:

I have a long page of links, each one opens in fancybox... when a user clicks a link and it opens a long page, as they scroll down to read the fancybox enclosed page, the background is scrolling too, therefore they lose their place in the parent document.

Comment: so many ways to do this ? did you tried to google `html static background`

Comment: with the latest version fancybox v2.1.3 the parent is not scrolled

Comment: @JFK Thanks so much, didn't know that and has solved the problem.